# WiFi Upload crashing on One PC on One network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, upload, speedtest

> Acer Aspire E15, MU-MIMO WiFi, Win10 x64, QCA 9377 Wireless Adaptor

I ran a few speedtests with different connections, networks, and devices:

- Laptop 1, WiFi on home router: Upload test crashes almost immediately.
- Laptop 1, LAN on home router: Upload test shows good upload.
- Android, WiFi on home router: Upload test is fine.
- Laptop 1, WiFi on Android 4G Hotspot: Upload test is fine.

Ran these multiple times. I concluded that specifically this laptop had a problem when using WiFi to connect to this specific home network.

Checked my router's page:
Laptop is connected to the 5GHz Frequency Band, 40MHz Channel Bandwidth.
All other devices seem to use 2.4 GHz Frequency Band, 20MHz Channel Bandwidth.

I don't really know how to solve the issue, because I don't know much about network configuration. All I know is I need the upload.
Do you know what might be wrong? Any leading ideas are welcome. Thanks in advance!
**EDIT:** I tried setting each band (2.4GHz then 5GHz) as preferred one by the WiFi Adapter, and updating drivers: didn't work.

Comment: Have you checked if Laptop 1 has a problem specific to use on the 5 GHz band?  If you can tell it to use the 2.4 GHz band instead, uploads will be slower but might still work.

Comment: I tried setting up the Wifi adapter to prefer the 2.4GHz band, but it didn't help. Test still crashed. Is there a way I can force it to use the 2.4GHz band? Other than the "properties > set preference" ?

Comment: Looks like you are still trying to use settings only on the Wifi adapter.  You may need to read all the instructions for the laptop, then tell the laptop, not the Wifi, to use the 2.4GHz band.  Or you might even need to tell them both to use the 2.4GHz band.